# How to setup output file in C#, to be enabled only if debug flag = true?

Tags: c#, file-io

Using C#, I would like to open an output file (for debug logging) only when specified by the user (`debug=true` flag). I have tried an approach with conditionals on the file opening, writing, and closing. The problem is that this will not compile, owing to the debug file not existing in context.

I suppose this is because the definition is buried in a conditional, but I am not sure how else to set it up. If I do not use the conditional, any pre-existing log gets wiped out, which I do not want.

What is the proper way to set this up, please?

Here is my test code:

```
using System;


public class DataProcessor

{
    public void process_data(string output_filepath, bool debug=false)
    {
        debug = true; // manual override for debugging

        if (debug == true)
        {
            System.IO.StreamWriter debug_file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(output_filepath);
        }

        for (int i=1; i<10; i++)
        {
            // do some other stuff     
            if (debug == true)
            {
                debug_file.WriteLine("output something: " + i);
            }
        }

        // do some other stuff

        if (debug == true)
        {
            debug_file.Close();
        }
    }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        DataProcessor data = new DataProcessor();

        string output_filepath = "debug_output.txt";
        data.process_data(output_filepath);
    }
}
```

And here are the error messages:

> Microsoft (R) Visual C# 2010 Compiler version 4.0.30319.1
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> conditional_stream_open.cs(20,17): error CS0103: The name 'debug_file' does not exist in the current context
>
> conditional_stream_open.cs(28,13): error CS0103: The name 'debug_file' does not exist in the current context
>
> Tool completed with exit code 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring `debug_file` inside of an `if` block.  It will be inaccessible outside of that context.

You need to move the declaration to the top of your method:

```
System.IO.StreamWriter debug_file = null; // added null here to avoid unassigned variable
```

and then inside the if statement:

```
debug_file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(output_filepath);
```

Comment: This makes sense now. But the second `if` statement (`WriteLine`) throws an error: "Use of unassigned local variable 'debug_file'". I am looking at this now.

Comment: You will need to initialize set `debug_file` to null in your declaration:  `System.IO.StreamWriter debug_file = null;`

Answer (score 2):

The `debug_file` is outside the scope, you should do like this

```
public void process_data(string output_filepath, bool debug=false)
    {
        debug = true; // manual override for debugging
System.IO.StreamWriter debug_file;
        if (debug == true)
        {
            debug_file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(output_filepath);
        }

        for (int i=1; i<10; i++)
        {
            // do some other stuff     
            if (debug == true)
            {
                debug_file.WriteLine("output something: " + i);
            }
        }

        // do some other stuff

        if (debug == true)
        {
            debug_file.Close();
        }
    }
```

Check using a debug symbol `#define` DEBUG instead of this approach.

Comment: You need to initialize `debug_file = null` otherwise the compiler will flag it as use of an unassigned variable.

Comment: DEBUG is a compile time symbol, not a runtime one. It also is automatically defined in debug builds so I don't think using the symbol would give the desired results (turning logging on/off depending on user options).